# New role assigned on user account update

Tags: rules, users

I'm thinking about writing a condition ("has new role(s)") using the Rules module to send an email to user to whom a new role is assigned. I need to know how to actually code this...

```
If (user has a new role(s)) {

  //   do something

}
```

I think that, by comparing whether a user has a role before saving and after saving or updating the content, one could tell whether a new role assigned. But I can't figure out how to code it and what API I should use. Please advise.

Comment: Rules has this out of the box, you don't need to code anything. Did you try to solve this yourself?

Comment: Right, just realised it can be done without coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a way to do it without coding. Works well so far.

**EVENT:** After updating an existing user account

**CONDITIONS:**

1) Data >> List contains item - LIST: "account-unchanged:roles", ITEM: "Role A" (Check NEGATE)

**AND**

2) Data >> List contains item - LIST: "account:roles", ITEM: "Role A"

**ACTION:** Send mail

Ref: http://goo.gl/Pcz2wN